# Overlapped data with messed up axises using facet_grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am using facet grid to generate neat presentations of my data.
Basically, my data frame has four columns:

idx, density, marker, case.

There are 5 cases, each case corresponds to 5 markers, and each marker corresponds to multiple idx, each idx corresponds to one density.

The data is uploaded here:
[data frame link](https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/EWYCQbi2Z8pJrzeAEmLjSkIB4X0uyyH7RgDkGeW4Vb96IQ?e=hSaVgy)

I tried to use facet_grid to achieve my goal, however, I obtained a really messed up graph:
[image]

The x-axis and y-axis are messed up, the codes are:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
plot.density <-
  ggplot(df_densityWindow, aes(x = idx, y = density)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(marker ~ case, scales = 'free') +
  background_grid(major = 'y', minor = "none") + # add thin horizontal lines
  panel_border() # and a border around each panel
plot(plot.density)
```

## EDIT:

I reupload the file, now it should be work:
[download file here](https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/EcH5aCswaf5BnEDYQVVGOs4Bb4w0FFvUK7xppzniKk7Ovg?e=PN21Xk)

Comment: Can you show `str(df_densityWindow)`? Are x and y some sort of factors?

Comment: The axes indicate that your input variables, `ids` and `density` are read as distinct, categorical values, not continuous data. So `ggplot` tries to label every single variable. Display the structure of your dataframe as other commentator commented, but I suspect the issue is partly related to how you loaded your data. Furthermore, the file you linked to came down empty on my computer.

Comment: @MrGumble Thank you for your comment! I added a new link and now it should be work!

Answer (score 0):

All 4 columns have been read as factors. This is an issue from however you loaded the data into R. Take a look at:

```
df <- readRDS('df.rds')
str(df)
'data.frame':   52565 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ idx    : Factor w/ 4712 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 1112 2223 3334 3546 3657 3768 3879 3990 2 ...
 $ density: Factor w/ 250 levels "1022.22222222222",..: 205 205 204 203 202 201 199 198 197 197 ...
 $ marker : Factor w/ 5 levels "CD3","CD4","CD8",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ case   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Case_1","Case_2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Good news is that you can fix it with:

```
df$idx <- as.integer(as.character(df$idx))
df$density <- as.numeric(as.character(df$density))
```

Although you should look into how you are loading the data, to avoid future.

As another trick, try the above code *without* using the `as.character` calls, and compare the differences.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by [MrGumble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57695838/3817004),  the `idx` and `density` variables are of type factor but should be plotted as numeric.

The `type.convert()` function does the  data conversion in one go:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
ggplot(type.convert(df_densityWindow), aes(x = idx, y = density))    + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(marker ~ case, scales = 'free') +
  background_grid(major = 'y', minor = "none") + # add thin horizontal   lines 
  panel_border() # and a border around each panel
```

[image]